# Creating lines between pairs of points

Tags: r, sp, sf

I have a sf dataframe *table_sf* as:

```
Classes ‘sf’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 12251 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ NOMBRE  : chr  "AL011900" "AL011900" "AL011900" "AL011900" ...
 $ FECHA   : POSIXct, format: "1900-08-27 00:00:00" "1900-08-27 06:00:00" "1900-08-27 12:00:00" "1900-08-27 18:00:00" ...
 $ INT     : num  18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ geometry:sfc_POINT of length 12251; first list element:  'XY' num  -42.1 15
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "ID" "NOMBRE" "FECHA" "INT"
```

I will like to create lines between sequential points per each *NOMBRE* and each line must have the *INT* column with the value of the first point used to create it.

That will be: the line from point 1 to point 2 will have the *INT* value of point 1. The line from point 2 to point 3 will have the *INT* value of point 2. And so on for each of the *NOMBRE*

My approach has been to loop through each pair of points of each *NOMBRE* and create the line using the *st_cast* function of the *sf* package BUT I'm still far from making it work.

Here is the code I have so far (packages tidyverse & sf):

```
for (i in table_sf %>% group_by(NOMBRE) %>% summarise()) {
  table_huracanes <- table_sf %>% 
    filter(NOMBRE == i) %>% 
    mutate(numb = row_number())
  for (h in table_huracanes$numb) {
    linea <- table_huracanes %>% 
      filter(numb <= 2) %>% 
      group_by(NOMBRE) %>% 
      summarise() %>% 
      st_cast("LINESTRING")
  }
}
```

I think I'm still missing a couple of things:

- Find a way in which I can select only two points for each of the
  second *for* loop.
- Create an empty sf dataframe (linestring or multilinestring?) where
  to append each *linea*.

To clarify, the table before creating the *sf* *dataframe* looks like this:

```
NOMBRE     LAT     LONG      FECHA                INT
AL011900    15  -42.1   1900-08-27T00:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.2    -43.4   1900-08-27T06:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.3    -44.7   1900-08-27T12:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.4    -45.6   1900-08-27T18:00:00Z    18.0054
AL021900    19  -59.3   1900-09-13T12:00:00Z    33.4386
AL021900    19.5    -60 1900-09-13T18:00:00Z    36.0108
AL021900    20  -60.6   1900-09-14T00:00:00Z    38.583
AL041905    36.3    -48.6   1905-10-10T18:00:00Z    46.2996
AL041905    37.9    -47.9   1905-10-11T00:00:00Z    43.7274
AL041905    39.6    -47.1   1905-10-11T06:00:00Z    41.1552
AL041905    41  -46 1905-10-11T12:00:00Z    41.1552
```

Note that for each *NOMBRE* there are different *INT* values. That's the reason why I need to create lines between each pair of points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` method of doing it, starting with your table from before converting to `sf`. The approach is to create a long-form table where each row is a start or end point, but include a `lineid` so that you can `group_by` on it and `summarise` to union the right points together, and then `st_cast` to `LINESTRING`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
table <- structure(list(NOMBRE = c("AL011900", "AL011900", "AL011900", "AL011900", "AL021900", "AL021900", "AL021900", "AL041905", "AL041905", "AL041905", "AL041905"), LAT = c(15, 15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 19, 19.5, 20, 36.3, 37.9, 39.6, 41), LONG = c(-42.1, -43.4, -44.7, -45.6, -59.3, -60, -60.6, -48.6, -47.9, -47.1, -46), INT = c(18.0054, 18.0054, 18.0054, 18.0054, 33.4386, 36.0108, 38.583, 46.2996, 43.7274, 41.1552, 41.1552)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(NOMBRE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), LAT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), LONG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), FECHA = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", "collector")), INT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

table_sf <- table %>%
  group_by(NOMBRE) %>%
  mutate(
    lineid = row_number(), # create a lineid
    LONG_end = lead(LONG), # create the end point coords for each start point
    LAT_end = lead(LAT)
  ) %>% 
  unite(start, LONG, LAT) %>% # collect coords into one column for reshaping
  unite(end, LONG_end, LAT_end) %>%
  filter(end != "NA_NA") %>% # remove nas (last points in a NOMBRE group don't start lines)
  gather(start_end, coords, start, end) %>% # reshape to long
  separate(coords, c("LONG", "LAT"), sep = "_") %>% # convert our text coordinates back to individual numeric columns
  mutate_at(vars(LONG, LAT), as.numeric) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONG", "LAT")) %>% # create points
  group_by(NOMBRE, INT, lineid) %>%
  summarise() %>% # union points into lines using our created lineid
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

plot(table_sf[, 1:2])
```

You can see in the plot that each line between two points has its own `INT` as requested.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `dplyr` with `sf`.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

### first, roughly recreate your dataset using nc data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% st_centroid()

nc$NOMBRE <- seq(1, nrow(nc)/2, 2) %>% as.character
nc$INT <- nc$NAME
nc %<>% arrange(NOMBRE) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:nrow(.))

nc <- select(nc, NOMBRE, INT, ID)

### create linestring for each NOMBRE, arranging by ID and grabbing the first INT
nc.line <- nc %>% group_by(NOMBRE) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  summarise(INT = first(INT), do_union = FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

Comment: The issue with your solution is that there are different _INT_ values on each _NOMBRE_. With your solution I only keep one _INT_ value for each _NOMBRE_ and I need one for each line between two points.